# Is it bad pratice to call a method from a CheckBox in UWP

Tags: mvvm, uwp

I am learning UWP with MVVM with Prism. I wanted to call a method om my ViewModel using a checkbox. here is the ViewModel.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

I was hoping to call this method directly from the xaml like this:

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox" Checked="{x:Bind ViewModel.DoSomething,Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Click me!" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ></CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

When I run the application I get the error:

```
Error       TwoWay binding target 'Checked' must be a dependency property
```

What does this mean?

Should I bind the IsChecked property to the ViewModel and raise an event?:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isChecked;
    event EventHandler checkedEvent;

    public bool isChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isChecked, value);
            checkedEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        checkedEvent += MainViewModel_checkedEvent;
    }

    private async void MainViewModel_checkedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DoSomething();
    }

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox" IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.isChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Click me!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ></CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: yes you answered your own question, you should always bind two way with a property and not a method, and when the property is set you can raise the event like you are already doing or you can even explore ICommand implementation in uwp apps.

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool isChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isChecked, value);
            checkedEvent?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            OnPropertyChanged("isChecked");
        }
    }
```

Also you can you can use OnPropertyChanged event for notifying property changes

Answer (score 0):

You can call a ViewModel method directly from the Click Event of the Checkbox.

```
        Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.DoSomething}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Remove the two way part. It can't work in an event. At most, make it OneWay, best OneTime if you can.
- Can X:Bind bind events to async Tasks? You may have to make it an async void, but try anyway